# Apache tiles didnt work because of dependencies

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I think I have a problem with two dependencies. First I have to resolve problem with SLF4J [https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder](http://Failed%20to%20load)

by adding a newest version of slf4j and my dependencies looks like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.0-alpha2</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But mi titles didn't compare with pages, now I don't have any error and I don't know what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs:
https://tiles.apache.org/framework/getting_started.html

You need an implementation of slf4j and commons logging - something like log4j.

As an alternative I'd suggest just using slf4j-simple.  This one dependency should resolve your logger requirement.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

You'll still need a log4j prop file.  You can take a look at mine to get an idea of where you should put it as well:

https://github.com/devaaron/log-prox/blob/master/src/main/resources/log4j.properties

Comment: No I have got error: `SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation` Answer is that _Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path_ but i don't know where is class path and from where can I take one of this jar